# Normalize data in object_construct in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake's Object_Construct to create a JSON.

Use case: Snowflake table has Person Title as

Person Name
Title_1
Title_2
Title_3

in JSON structure, I need to transform this as
"Person_Title"[
{ "Title_1",
"Title_1_desc"
},
{"Title_2",
"Title_2_desc"
},
{"Title_3",
"Title_3_desc"
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Below example outlines the placement of functions to get the output.
Though not sure if you are looking for any sort of dynamism, which following example does not gives -

```
with cte (Person_Name, Title_1, Title_2, Title_3) as (
 select 'name-1','t1-desc-1','t2-desc-1','t3-desc-1' union all
 select 'name-2','t1-desc-2','t2-desc-2','t3-desc-2' union all
 select 'name-3','t1-desc-3','t2-desc-3','t3-desc-3'
)
select object_construct('Person_title',
 array_construct(
 object_construct('Title_1',Title_1),
 object_construct('Title_2',Title_2),
 object_construct('Title_3',Title_3))) output_json
from cte;

+------------------------------+
| OUTPUT_JSON                  |
|------------------------------|
| {                            |
|   "Person_title": [          |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_1": "t1-desc-1" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_2": "t2-desc-1" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_3": "t3-desc-1" |
|     }                        |
|   ]                          |
| }                            |
| {                            |
|   "Person_title": [          |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_1": "t1-desc-2" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_2": "t2-desc-2" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_3": "t3-desc-2" |
|     }                        |
|   ]                          |
| }                            |
| {                            |
|   "Person_title": [          |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_1": "t1-desc-3" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_2": "t2-desc-3" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "Title_3": "t3-desc-3" |
|     }                        |
|   ]                          |
| }                            |
+------------------------------+
```

Query with dynamism -

```
with cte (Person_Name, Title_1, Title_2, Title_3) as (
  select 'name-1','t1-desc-1','t2-desc-1','t3-desc-1' union all
  select 'name-2','t1-desc-2','t2-desc-2','t3-desc-2'
)
select object_construct('Person_title',
  array_agg(object_construct(TITLE_DESC,TITLE))) as output_col
from
(select * from cte
  unpivot (title for title_desc in (Title_1, Title_2, Title_3))
)
group by Person_Name;

+------------------------------+
| OUTPUT_COL                   |
|------------------------------|
| {                            |
|   "Person_title": [          |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_1": "t1-desc-1" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_2": "t2-desc-1" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_3": "t3-desc-1" |
|     }                        |
|   ]                          |
| }                            |
| {                            |
|   "Person_title": [          |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_1": "t1-desc-2" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_2": "t2-desc-2" |
|     },                       |
|     {                        |
|       "TITLE_3": "t3-desc-2" |
|     }                        |
|   ]                          |
| }                            |
+------------------------------+
```